# How do I I create a simple javascript page, allowing the user to enter text & display it?

Tags: javascript, html

I took a web programming courses a while ago but I'm essentially relearning everything from scratch.

I just want to build a very simply page using html/javascript that has a box for the user to enter a question or a phrase and a submit button.

When the user presses the submit button, the question/phrase instantly shows up in a bubble below. Each question/phrase must show up in a separate bubble and you can enter multiple questions/phrases.

I'm looking for suggestions of ways to accomplish this task using javascript.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Hung up on anything in particular?  Your sort of answering your own question.  First, create the html with the elements you need.  Next, create the javascript to handle the submit button's "click" event to display your "bubble" (probably a div element).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using jQuery, an awesome javascript library that makes things easier.

http://jquery.com/

They have great tutorials at http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

With ajax and forms at http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Safer_Contact_Forms_Without_CAPTCHAs#Simple_Contact_Form: